# Android MediaPlayer support for MIDI with DLS Soundbank

Tags: android-mediaplayer, midi

The android documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) indicates that the android MediaPlayer can playback (a) MIDI and (b) DLS.

I have a midi file (single track) and have a DLS soundbank. I would like to playback the midi file using the android MediaPlayer, using the DLS soundbank.

Can you please provide a code example to achieve the above?

Comment: You need to put them into an [XMF file](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/xmf/xmf.php).

Comment: Thanks @CL. I did research on the XMF authoring tools and it appears that the standard is dead as far as adoption is concerned. The below link nails this fact: http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Extensible_Music_Format_(XMF)#Tools. If you are aware of any tooling support for XMF, that'd be very helpful.